# suppress TS2305 Module has no exported member error when using Typescript

Tags: typescript

We start to use typescript with wechat mini program development. There is this annoying yet harmless error when we compile the project:

[image: something like this]

The project would still run, but because the quirk of wechat mini program/typescript, this error would persist. I tried using `eslint-disable-line` or `eslint-disable` with no effect...

Here is how to test/simulate it:

In file a:

```
const App = () => {};
const Page = () => {};
const wx = {}, _wx = { App, Page };

module.exports = {
  wx: { ...wx, ..._wx },
  App: _wx.App,
  Page: _wx.Page
}
```

Note, here we can't use:

```
export {
   wx: { ...wx, ..._wx },
   App: _wx.App,
   Page: _wx.Page
}
```

because it is grammatically incorrect and we are not allowed to modify

```
const App = () => {};
const Page = () => {};
const wx = {}, _wx = { App, Page };
```

(imagine they are injected code instead of codes you actually write)

and in file b, you have:

```
import { wx, App, Page } from 'file_a'
import ... from '...'
```

Note `import { wx, App, Page } from 'file_a'` must be on the top.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `// @ts-ignore` on top of `import { wx, App, Page } from 'file_a'`

Comment: I would recommend adding a comment of what exactly you're trying to ignore, like this 
`// @ts-ignore: has no exported member 'wx'`